# Can not change the state to 'Processing': target method was not found

Tags: c#, hangfire

I am currently working with Hangfire server. i am using two server instances on same pc to enqueue job in the hangfire server.

Here is the sample of Hangfire server instance1. same for server instance two.

```
var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
        {
            ServerName = "hangfireserver1",
            //Queues = new string[] { "queue1" },
            WorkerCount = 1
        };

        using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer(options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hangfire Server1 started. Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

i am using only 1 worker count for each server instance.

and my enqueue job process is given below,

```
string jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => t.Process(Type, cp));
```

When i enqueue job then it is not changing to "Processing" state, error is coming like below,

> Can not change the state to 'Processing': target method was not found.

So i am getting no idea what i am missing or any issue in this process.

Comment: `string jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => t.Process(Type, cp)).FirstOrDefault()`